# Android game: what is the best game engine and its importance?

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I know that there are a lot of questions about android games, but I didn't find an important thing. Are game engines so important to develop an android game? Can I develop it without them, only with android studio? I can create animations only with android studio. I don't know what these game engines make, but I need to know it. I'm trying to create an android game and I need to know if it's important use game engines. Well, if they exist, it means that they are important. So, what is the best game engine for android (java)? There a lot of game engines on the web !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small list of "game engines" and framework you might like :

- Pure android (for small games)
- Unity (can build to Android, IOS and more, which is nice)
- Libgdx

There are in order of complexity. You might prefer going for unity if you're making a small or medium game. Even with no knowledge, it's pretty easy to start coding, there's a lot of documentation and the community is big. I think you might learn more in game developement by using unity.

Since android isn't a game engine per se, you'll maybe not find the resources you'd want, but it can be a lot more interesting, as you'll learn to use the phone capabilities, and you'll code in native language.

When you're better at coding, and want to make stuff "from scratch", you should try out libgdx. It's **WAY HARDER**, but you'll have a total control on what and how your game do everything. It's not a full engine though, so you'll have to code a lot of stuff yourself. That's why Unity is easier, everything is there, from the graphics engine, to the physics engine, and in a unified way, if you get what i mean.

They are other engines though, I'm just listing the one I know, based on your need and current knowledge.

Comment: You don't say how these game engines can help me. P.s. I'm not a newbie

Comment: Also Unit is for c++

Comment: 1. Unity is C#, UnityScript
2. I told you that these engine may help you make games quick because of low learning curves
3. If you weren't a newbie, you should now that.

Comment: Okay thanks. But I can create animations only with android studio,for example. What is the difference between creating animations in android studio and with libgdx? (Simple animations) What are the vantages?

Comment: What do you mean by "creatin animations with android" ? Translation and rotation and such? Or sprite animation? The first one, you will have to code the transformation yourself, like increasing a position value and drawing at the position each frame. For the other, you'll have to use a spritesheet maybe, and use the existing classes to animate your sprites. You can do some researches on how to do this, it's a common question on the subject.

Comment: Ok. Can I create sprite animations with only android studio?

Comment: Yes, you can. You should search on the internet for this kind of questions, not here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default **Android Studio** to create games, people even create games on c++ without any graphic libraries, just **console**. But if you want to create really good games, you can use ready engines, as for example **Unity**, which is free now. However, it would take a lot of time. Otherwise, you can google any other engines for android.

*P.S. start with android studio to understand how android works and just to learn programming.*

Comment: You don't say how these game engines can help me. P.s. I'm not a newbie

Comment: The core functionality typically provided by a game engine includes a rendering engine (“renderer”) for 2D or 3D graphics, a physics engine or collision detection (and collision response), sound, scripting, animation, artificial intelligence, networking, streaming, memory management, threading, localization support, scene graph, and may include video support for cinematics. The process of game development is often economized, in large part, by reusing/adapting the same game engine to create different games or to make it easier to "port" games to multiple platforms. From Wikipedia